# Install and configure lightdm for KUbuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, lightdm

I'd like to use lightdm with KDE Plasma on Kubuntu 18.04.

Just installing and selecting it as dm leads to a session failed. There used to be a lightdm-kde-greeter package, but this is not available in 18.04.

How should I proceed? Thanks for any help! Here is the config:

```
~$ cat /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-kde-plasma-kf5.conf
```

[SeatDefaults]
user-session=kde-plasma-kf5

Comment: can you show `cat /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-kde-plasma-kf5.conf` ? Please edit your question for that.

Comment: done that. I've also tested lightdm on another machine (that was running kde neon, not kubuntu, but the base is the same), I had the same problem there.

Comment: maybe helpful,take a look here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-workspace/+bug/1629543

Comment: Seems like the exact issue I am having, I'll try the fix later. Thanks!

Comment: The workaround in the given link works for me, so this is a correct answer, thank you!